# is it possible to get the futter path dynamic in terminal when using fvm

Tags: flutter, macos, shell, terminal

I am written a shell script to upgrade the flutter dependencies in terminal. this is the shell script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u

set -e

set -x

# https://flutter.cn/community/china
export PUB_HOSTED_URL=https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/dart-pub
export FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL=https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/flutter

~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter pub upgrade
```

now I changed to using [fvm](https://github.com/fluttertools/fvm) to manage the flutter version, the version always swithed by time. is it possible to get the current flutter version dynamic in terminal so that I did not need to change the shell script even the flutter upgrade or changed the execute path. I have tried this way to print the current path seems did not work:

```
➜  retire git:(master) ✗ fvm list
Cache Directory:  /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/fvm/versions

2.10.5
2.10.3
2.8.0
2.5.1
➜  retire git:(master) ✗ whereis flutter
flutter:
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1: `flutter --version`
step 2: `flutter doctor -v`
after performing 2nd step you will get to know your flutter sdk path which clearly mention in 2nd line of your output.

if you want to update flutter, proceed with this command:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: I want get the flutter execute file full path dynamic, the flutter command did not exists in terminal. @Krina chauhan I could not use the flutter command in terminal because the version was managed by fvm.